# Parsing XML and manipulate the extracted data in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Please assist me to extract data from XML, I am scrambling to find a logic with little knowledge in Java.

PS: Program will be executed on a  larger XML file (2GB xml file), it should not take more than 10 mins to complete the process, is there something we can do to mutli-thread and reduce the processing time ?
Please guide me the java libs that I should for this purpose.

PFB the sample XML input and expected output.

```
<ABC-PROCESS>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-14</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>F637A146-3437AB82-BA659D4A-17AC7FBF</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-14</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>F637A146-3437AB82-BA659D4A-17AC7FBF</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-3</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>D6306210-CF424F11-8E2D3496-E6CE1CA7</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>D6306210-CF424F11-8E2D3496-E6CE1CA7</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-3</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>4EFR02B4-ADFDAF12-3C123II2-ADAFADFD</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-14</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>5D2702B2-ECE8F1FB-3CEC3229-5FE4C4BC</KEY>
</H>
</ABC-PROCESS>
```

FINAL OUTPUT:

```
PRIOIRTY KEY  HITS  
1        1    2
-3       1    1
-14      2    3
```

Logic of above expected output  is explained below:

1nd and 2nd Hit tag has Priority -14 and grouped into one common KEY, and the max prioirty is -14.

Output Slab for first 2 hits:

```
PRIOIRTY KEY  HITS  
-14        1     2
```

3rd and 4th Hit tag has maximum Priority 1 with one common KEY.
Output Slab:

```
PRIOIRTY KEY  HITS  
1        1     2
```

5th H tag has one Priority -3 with one common KEY.
Output Slab:

```
PRIOIRTY KEY  HITS  
-3       1     1
```

6th H tag has one Priority -3 with one common KEY.
Output Slab:

```
PRIOIRTY KEY  HITS  
-14       1     1
```

FINAL OUTPUT (Aggregated):

```
PRIOIRTY KEY  HITS  
1        1    2
-3       1    1
-14      2    3
```

Comment: What have you tried till now?